# How to show logs on dashboard using filebeat and logstash

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am beginner in elastic search.I have done configuration part . I can see my logs output in logstash and filebeat both but only i am facing to display that logs on dashboard.
Please help me to show logs on dashboard.

Comment: Where is your issue Veeru? Have you tried to follow any documentation/tutorial? Could you add that information to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Elasticsearch, the best solution for you is to use the default filebeat dashboards.
With few configurations, Filebeat can load predefined dashboards  suitable for most use cases.
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-dashboards.html#:~:text=Filebeat%20comes%20packaged%20with%20example,can%20run%20the%20setup%20command](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-dashboards.html#:%7E:text=Filebeat%20comes%20packaged%20with%20example,can%20run%20the%20setup%20command).

If you change the YML file, the dashboard will be re initiated after each filebeat restart.
If you want to load them only once, you should be able to execute it with the CLI once :

```
./filebeat setup -E "setup.kibana.host=http://localhost:5601" --dashboards
```

Comment: I have tried with this solution but didn't worked .Adding my documentation to review better .input {
        beats {
            host => "localhost"
            port => "5044"
        }
    }
 filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
 date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
   }
    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
  }
}

Comment: ***Filebeat Configuration Example #


filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:/elk/spring-boot-elk.log

setup.dashboards.enabled: true

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

Comment: Could you give more details ? the provided command is only to initiate the default dashboards on kibana. Do you filebeat send data to elastic ? (go to developer console in kibana and use the query : GET filebeat*/_search 
Do you have any answer in here ? 
Does the kibana index pattern exist ? 
Do you see any errors in the filebeat logs ?

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to use logstash ? If you are new to elastic, it will be most productive to connect your filebeat directly with elasticsearch. Then you don't need any logstash.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I have tried with : GET filebeat*/_search on filebeat console i got 200 response code .Means its is okay.

Comment: Actually what i am trying to do is ,I have two Apache logs file .I can see the logs in discover module .but when i tried to show the logs on dashboard .I am getting no result found on [Filebeat Apache] Access and error logs ECS. How i can achive this .

Comment: At first, be sure no filters block the visualization to find data, and check date interval. 
Then, Refresh the kibana index pattern, and check if it works.
Ensure file beat and kibana/elastic has the same version. (the support are based on ECS so with older version you could maybe have an issue) 
If it does not work. Edit a visualization and compare used fields to your Discover to find what's wrong. (but it should work out of the box)

Comment: Thanks , I am working since very long time .I will try the configuration but if possible can you please give me Apache filebeat configuration.  That helps  more .

Comment: I use to use the default config.   
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-apache.html with just enabling the module, configure file path, init the dashboard, and launch filebeat as a service.